# Store data from multiple inputs php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dynamic form where user can choose the number of inputs. I don't know how many input the form could have and I'd like to store the results in an array.
Here my HTML :

```
<select name="number-children" id="number-children">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery :

```
$("#number-children").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    var count = Number($("#number-children option:selected").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      str += '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="child-'+i+'">Child ' + i
              + '</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="child-'+i+'" class="form-control" id="child-'+i+'"></input></div>';
   }
   $("#children").html(str);
});
```

How can I add each input's value into an array to collect it in a post php request ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just Change

```
<input type="text" name="child-'+i+'" class="form-control" id="child-'+i+'"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="child['+i+']" class="form-control" id="child-'+i+'"></input>
```

Comment: To append the answer of Abdus, you can then use $_POST['child'] as an array containing the values of i as keys, and input field values as values;

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solved my problem ! Thanks to @jeroen too !

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
 $("#children").html(str);
```

To :

```
$("#children").append(str);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to send the dynamic data now !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get all children in 1 array, is to use an array in html:

```
str += '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="child-'+i+'">Child ' + i
          + '</label> <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="child[]" class="form-control" id="child-'+i+'"></input></div>';
                                                                           ^^ here
```

Now when you send the form, you will have all values as an array in `$_POST['child']` so you can easily loop over them regardless of the number.